# Customized OpenCart Remove From Cart Issue

Tags: php, opencart, opencart-module

New to OpenCart and running a customized version of 1.5.5.1. I am having some issues with 'Remove' from cart:

1. I can see from dumping the `$_SESSION` that I have

   ```
   [cart] => Array([88:base64_encoded(serialized($option)=] => 1)`
   ```

   and

   ```
   [key] => 88:base64_encoded(serialized($option)=,
   ```

but the

```
 $this->cart->remove($this->request->get['remove'])
```

is only removing the `[cart]` and not `[key]`.

I begin with the following by adding an item to the cart:

```
[cart] => Array ( [88:YTo1OntpOjMyMDtzOjM6IjMwOCI7aTozMjE7czozOiIzMDYiO2k6MzIyO3M6MzoiMzA1IjtpOjMyMztzOjM6IjMxMCI7aTozMjQ7czozOiIzMDkiO30=] => 1 ) [key] => 88:YTo1OntpOjMyMDtzOjM6IjMwOCI7aTozMjE7czozOiIzMDYiO2k6MzIyO3M6MzoiMzA1IjtpOjMyMztzOjM6IjMxMCI7aTozMjQ7czozOiIzMDkiO30=
```

And on removing it, I am left with:

```
[cart] => Array ( ) [key] => 88:YTo1OntpOjMyMDtzOjM6IjMwOCI7aTozMjE7czozOiIzMDYiO2k6MzIyO3M6MzoiMzA1IjtpOjMyMztzOjM6IjMxMCI7aTozMjQ7czozOiIzMDkiO30=
```

2. I would like to refresh the `route=product/category&path=##` on the removal from the mini-cart in the header, but am stumped as to where to look for that.

Thanks for any direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. After discussing this in chat it appears you are dealing with modified code that uses a non-standard index called 'key'.  This might be a mistake and there is no easy way to determine what it's purpose is.  As it is, the `cart->remove()` method appears to be working as expected.
2. If you want a refresh just append `location.reload();` to the `onclick` event in the mini-cart template.

Comment: Why does it not also remove the `[key]`?

According to `system/library/cart.php` it should

    `if(isset($this->session->data['cart'][$key])) {
        unset($this->session->data['cart'][$key]);
    }`

Comment: Please revise your question and clarify what you are asking.  It does remove the `key`.

Comment: It does not remove `[key]`, only `[cart]`

Comment: I have revised the question to [hopefully] be more concise

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93089/discussion-between-macgregor-and-billynoah).